# Wordpress - Adding editor content to a page with a template

Tags: wordpress, themes, editor, wysiwyg

In most Wordpress themes, they make use of Wordpress templates that can be chosen for a page. Now, in this particular theme, when you choose a template for a page, it discards the content you add in the editor section.

Surely you should be able to enable this somewhere? How can this be done or does it differ from theme to theme?

Answer (score 0):

Add the loop and `the_content()` template tag in the page template. Look at the `page.php` template in your theme folder for the exact markup needed for your theme:

```
    // Start the Loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php the_title( '<header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1></header>' ); ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
    <?php
        the_content();
        wp_link_pages();
    ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
<?php
    endwhile;
```